# How to enable developer options on Huawei device (Cloud debugging) for using Fake GPS?

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery-connect, huawei-map-kit

I don't have a physical Huawei device so I use Huawei Cloud Debugging to test my app.

However, I can't test all features without using a fake gps location.

I didn't find such a function in the emulator itself, so I want to do it with a third party fake gps emulation app. But for this I need to enable developer mode, on real Huawei devices this is done through the “Settings”>” System”>” About Phone” and tapping 7 times on “Build Number”, but when I click even 20 times on the menu item, nothing happens!
Also, clicking on any other field in the device information does not help - the developer mode does not turn on

I will be very grateful if you tell me how to emulate the user's location in any way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We contacted Huawei representatives and it turned out that at the moment the geolocation mock on the emulator is available only for developers from China

However, Huawei representatives can provide a physical device for development (contact them for details)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it on remote devices because currently, Huawei Cloud Debugging does not have the option for users to enable developer options on the remote devices. You better have a real Huawei device to test your app. After enabling the developer options on the device (Settings ->System->About Phone and tapping 7 times on Build number), then from Settings->System & updates, you will see the Developer options. Finally, you can enable the Fake GPS app (assume you install it on the device) from "Select mock location app" in the developer options.

Comment: yes i know, since we contacted huawei representatives directly, i described it in my answer